# Record pc screen from a second pc with Ubuntu installed and launch an script

Tags: video, hdmi, external-hdd

I need to record the screen of what's happening on a first pc on a second one and use the video at the second computer running his own Ubuntu system (not sharing the screen as in remote way). I then need to launch a script at the second pc that is gonna take data from the video record.

[I have checked some external HDMI cards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290971/how-to-capture-from-hdmi-with-ubuntu) and I plan to buy one to do the task, but I wonder if my second pc could take the video in live at a screen/smartTV working at the second pc, running a different desktop etc than the first one, where the video comes from.

Comment: I really feel unclear reading this question.  I do have an installation where on a weekly basis, I take video from a second computer, and do stuff with it.  the parts that confuse me are *"... to launch a script using the video."* and *"..at a seperated system from the first one..."*.  Can you expand on your question, please?

Comment: My english is not good but I will try it @Charles Green

Comment: And *I* will try hard to understand!

Comment: @Charles Green I need to run a program on the first pc. Then I cannot launch a script on a second pc that takes info from the first program by video. I need to record the video, make screenshoots and use that info. I know how to do that with a single pc, but for some reasons outside the question this should be done at a second pc. I could use a remote access maybe, but I am asking to do it via HDMI. To connect my laptop to the screen were the pc is running and take the video record of what is being doing on the first pc, but run the script/programm at a separated environment/desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps if I describe the system that I have been running, it will answer your question?

At my church, we are running two separate computers - one with Windows 7 for the purpose of displaying slides and graphics, and one with Ubuntu which is used both to record audio, and live stream sermons to facebook.

The Ubuntu computer accepts USB feeds from audio, a movie camera, and using a [DVI-to-USB](https://www.epiphan.com/products/avio-hd/) converter the screen output from the Windows computer.

On the Ubuntu computer I am using [OBS-Studio](https://obsproject.com/) (available in the repositories of Ubuntu) to combine the two video feeds and the Audio feed, which is then streamed live to Facebook.

So, if I have read your question correctly, I am using Ubuntu to look at and record, the video from a different desktop (on a different OS!) and manipulate that video in Ubuntu.

Comment: I will try that DVI-to-USB. I will wait a bit for the bounty but looks what I was searching for. Ty! –

Comment: @Universal_learner There are several that will work, but I seemed to destroy the less expensive ones without trying.

Comment: Knowing it is possible I will search a bit for more info/cheap converters to get the screen output